# How to remove the extension icon from the extensions bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and I have tried almost everything to get feedly mini toolkit like user interface. [Feedly: read more, know more.](https://feedly.com/)

This provides an extension feedly mini toolkit, which gets integrated into the browser as shown in image.[image: feedly mini toolkit example]

I want to do something like that with my extension. I dont want to show it in chrome setting/extension bar but on a particular page like feedly.

**The Question is**: How to create something like feedly mini toolkit shown in the red box in the image which is there on a browser page and not in the chrome settings bar.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: is that not clear from the title? I updated the description and title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `browserAction` field from your `manifest.json` file.

Comment: that I am able to do and did already but I dont want to show the extension icon in chrome settings bar. this feedly mini toolkit is an extension which you can add to chrome but you will never find it in settings bar it will be there on DOM only.

Comment: So your question is: how to remove the extension icon from the extensions bar?

Comment: ok. Well, I tried removing default_popup and default_icon from browser_action. I should have tried removing browser_action. It works!